# MVC6: determine if current user has access to controller method based on controller and action name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Given a controller method like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [CustomAuthorization] // NOTE THAT CUSTOM AUTHORIZATION IS ALSO USED.
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExecuteControllerMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

> How do I **determine** from the **controller name**, and **method name** whether or not the method is accessible to the current user?

Is there a way, either from the **url to the controller method**, or as above from the **method** and **controller** name whether or not a controller method is accessible?

Comment: Controlling from users role is enough for you or not?

Comment: No I want to interrogate the framework - same way a unit test might test a custom authorization attribute. Checking roles is trivial. I need a more comprehensive approach